# User-mode TCP stack for retransmits over lossy serial link

Tags: c, linux, windows, tcp, serial-port

I believe that my question is:

Is there a simple user-mode TCP stack on PC operating systems that could be used to exchange data over a lossy serial link with a Linux-based device?

Here is more context:

I have a Linux-based device connected via a serial link to a PC. The serial link is lossy so data being sent between the two devices sometimes needs to be retransmitted. Currently the system uses a custom protocol that includes framing, addressing (for routing to different processes within the Linux device), and a not-so-robust retransmission algorithm.

On the Linux device side, it would be convenient to replace the custom protocol, implement SLIP over the serial link and use TCP for all communications. The problem is that on the PC-side, we're not sure how to use the host's TCP stack without pulling in general IP routing that we don't need. If there were a user-mode TCP stack available, it seems like I could integrate that in the PC app. The only TCP stacks that I've found so far are for microcontrollers. They could be ported, but it would be nice if there were something more ready-to-go. Or is there some special way to use the OS's built in TCP stack without needing administrative privileges or risking IP address conflicts with the real Ethernet interfaces.

Lastly, just to keep the solution focused on TCP, yes, there are other solutions to this problem such as using HDLC or just fixing our custom protocol. However, we wanted to explore the TCP route further in case it was an option.

Comment: Not sure it is relevant, but what about using a (free and famous) proprietary protocol, available on both Linux and Windows, like [kermit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_\(protocol\))

Comment: "Lossy" as in analog lossy, or "lossy" as in "unreliable"?

Comment: On small microcontroller systems I have used HDLC for this.  On a Linux or embedded Linux system you can use PPP which will work out of the box with no effort and allow you to connect to a windows machine easily.

Comment: @InkBlend - lossy as in unreliable

Comment: @ring0 - yeah, I suppose that there's some way to put kermit in, or for that matter Z-modem, X-modem, etc. I was hoping that an IP solution were possible, just since it would integrate much more nicely with a few components.

Comment: @Frank well I'm not much of a windozian, but I guess [hope] someone was able to add an IP layer on top of the basic serial protocol, then a TCP stack on top of that, on Windows. The thing is, the "all-serial" period and the IP period did not really overlap - of course serial is still used - but the average Windows-shareware-dev may not  have seen that need as vital.

Comment: @TJD - PPP as a protocol is fine, but doesn't the Windows PPP stack make the link a generally routable IP interface? I'd prefer that the use of TCP not be visible outside of the app, since non-tech savvy people will be using the app. It would be better if their network settings were not modified.

Comment: @FrankHunleth, that's true.  But being able to use built-in SW as opposed to developing, maintaining, supporting something custom is a pretty huge advantage.  I think you should be able to get around the non-tech savvy configuration issue by having your app's installer do the config automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the comments have already answered your question, but perhaps to clarify; No you can not use TCP without using IP. TCP is built on top of IP, and it isn't going to work any other way.

PPP is a good way of establishing an IP connection over a serial link, but if you do not have administrative access on both sides of the computer this could be difficult. 172.16.x, 10.x, and 192.168.x are defined as being open for local networks, so you should be able to find a set of IP addresses that does not interfere with the network operation of the local computer.

From the point of view of no configuration, no dependencies, comping up with your own framing / re-transmit protocol should not be too hard, and is probably your best choice if you don't need inter-operability. That being said kermit, {z,y,z}modem would provide both better performance and a standard to code against.

Lastly, you may be able to use something like socat to do protocol translation. I.e. connect a serial stream to a TCP port. That wouldn't address data reliability / re-transmission, but it may be the interface you are looking to program against.

Comment: Right. It's the desire to avoid requiring administrative access on the PC side that makes using TCP harder than it feels like it should be. I was hoping that there'd be some clever way of using an existing TCP/IP stack within my app and scoping it so that it wouldn't interfere with local networking, but that doesn't look like it's the case. Thanks for adding your answer.